# Using user-supplied database credentials across multiple pages

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am learning to use MySQL with PHP and while practicing, I tried to create a simple web application using Core PHP and MySQL. It is summarized below:

-It has a pretty simple html page where username(uname) and password(pword) for MySQL are input in a form and are sent by POST method to a PHP script called PHP1.php

-PHP1 makes connection to MySQL. The code is(skipping PHP tags):

```
//Get input username and password
$username = $_POST['uname'];
$password = $_POST['pword'];
//Server information
$server = "localhost";
//Connect
$conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password);
//Check success/failure
if ($conn -> connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed".$conn->connect_error);
}
```

After connecting, PHP1 retrieves information about the databases stored in the respective account and displays radio buttons to select the database and sends the name of the selected database by GET method to another script PHP2.php

-In PHP2.php I want to display the TABLES in the selected database.
However, when control is transferred to PHP2.php, connection to MySQL is terminated. I first tried to include my PHP1.php file in PHP2.php and use the $conn variable but ofcourse it'll try to reconnect to MySQL due to the above mentioned code and at the same time, the first request containing uname and pword is lost resulting in an authentication error.

How can I overcome this problem?

EDIT:
I have seen other questions here but all of them have fixed usernmae/passwords and so  the connection script can be placed in a separate file easily. I require to take username and password from the user.

Comment: I do something different with `mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $databasename);` which works pretty well. If you want an example of this I will post below since you are using `new mysqli()` I am not sure how that works

Comment: @Travis Your method makes connection to a database the moment it is logged in but i want to do it later after getting information from user.

Comment: at each page do you connect to different mysql databases, with different `username` and `password` ?

Comment: @TheLastStark I have multiple databases created in a single MySQL account and i want to give the user the choice of selecting the database and connecting to it and afterwards show the tables in the selected database.

Comment: _BIG Note_ It is VERY unusual that a web site/web app would use a users specific Username/Password to actually connect to the database. It is far more normal that the PHP scripts use One Specific Account and Password to make conections to the database.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to connect to different databases with different password and username without re-establishing a new connection.

Comment: i am doing it for the sake of practice only. But thanks a lot for letting me know that this sort of things is not used practically :)  solution using sessions works as i want it to.

Comment: I see, I thought you wanted to use a new database without reconnecting with new username or password, I misunderstood this sentence "but ofcourse it'll try to reconnect to MySQL", Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) which will persist the session variables across pages:

**PHP1**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $username = $_POST['uname'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $password = $_POST['pword'];

$server = "localhost";
$conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password);
```

**PHP2**

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];

$server = "localhost";
$conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password);
```

In PHP1 you're going to want to check that the `$_POST` values are set and in other pages you'll want to check that the `$_SESSION` variables are set.  See [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).